# How to populate foreign key values in a Hibernate + Spring JPA configuration when parent/child objects are persisted at the same time?

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two objects, Parent and Child.  Child has a foreign key back to PARENT_ID field in PARENT table (MySQL database).

When a Parent and Child object are created/assembled at the same time, and persist is called, the Child PARENT_ID foreign key is not automatically populated.

Sample Code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARENT")
public class Parent {
    @Column(name = "PARENT_ID")
    private Long parentId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    private List<Child> children;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "CHILD")
public class Child {
    @Column(name = "CHILD_ID")
    private Long childId;

    @Column(name = "PARENT_ID")
    private Long parentId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Parent parent;
}
```

I have two samples for persistence:

1) Using a Hibernate EntityManager:

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;

...

em.persist(parent);
```

2) Using a Spring Data JPA JpaRepository instance:

```
public interface ParentRepository extends JpaRepository<Parent, Long> {

}
```

And in my ParentServiceImpl:

```
@Autowired
private ParentRepository parentRepository;

...

public Parent save(Parent parent) {
    return parentRepository.save(parent);
}
```

What is the recommended strategy to go about populating the foreign key?  Should the Parent object be persisted first and then the Child object foreign key set at that point?  Or is there a way to persist it all at once with the foreign key being set automatically or by reference?

Edit: Persistence samples added.

**Edit 2 (fixed!): Problem solved as per Ryan Stewart's second point.  I removed the Long parentId field from the Child object and put the @Column reference for the parentId on the getter.  Also made sure to set-up references correctly (importantly Child reference back to Parent).**

Comment: Show the code you use to persist both.

Comment: Done!  I only do a single persist call in both examples.  Cascades all work for updates and inserts where the parent foreign key is pre-set (Parent saved first).

Comment: Show us the full code. How do you construct the parent and the child. How do you associate them? You're talking about cascades, but you don't have any in the code you posted. If you want us to explain how your code must be fixed, post the code you're using.

Comment: The code is complex so I wanted to focus in on the specific problem I was having with a simple case.  Ryan Stewart's response solved the problem (his 2nd point).  Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That code has two things preventing it from working:

1. Your entities have no `@Id`. You probably just left it off because this is an example, but it's worth pointing out.
2. You've double-mapped the column `parent_id`. Child has both a Long field and a Parent field mapped to the same column. Get rid of the Long. It's the Parent relationship you're after.

After that, what you have there is a completely traditional bidirectional one-to-many with a join column. If it's not working for you, then you're doing something wrong in the code where you create and save them. Very probably, you're not creating the objects properly. Correct code using these entities would look something like this:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
Parent p = new Parent();
Child child = new Child();
child.parent = p;
Child child1 = new Child();
child1.parent = p;
p.children = Arrays.asList(child, child1);
session.save(p);
session.save(p.children.get(0));
session.save(p.children.get(1));
tx.commit();
```

Note especially that the child should be set in the parent as well as the parent in the child. Don't build a half-broken object model and expect Hibernate to clean up your mess. Many people ignore this seemingly obvious requirement and wonder why Hibernate seems unstable and/or unreliable.

Comment: You were correct in point #1, I did exclude them as I was trying to simplify things (perhaps a bit too much).  Your point #2 did the trick!  Thanks!  Is there a reason why you explicitly save child records in your example?  In a complex domain, that would seem rather cumbersome (I have about 20 objects descending off my primary object in a variety of relationships).  I don't explicitly save any child records at all and everything is working great now (inserts and updates all working beautifully)!!

Comment: @skel625: I saved everything explicitly because the entities you posted had no cascading set up, and cascading is off by default, meaning the children won't be saved unless you do it yourself. With saves cascading, there's no reason to do that, of course.

Comment: Ahhhhh yes that makes perfect sense!  Thanks for the help, much appreciated!