# JPA Foreign Key Constraint Fails on EntityManager flush

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, intellij-idea

I've been following the NetBeans AffableBean e-commerce tutorial, but using IntelliJ as my IDE instead. I have gotten everything working up until the point where I need to add Customers to the database, as well as a CustomerOrder relating to the order they are placing. The section of the tutorial is visible here:

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/transaction.html#placeOrder

When I place an order, I receive the following error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`larrys`.`customer_order`, CONSTRAINT `fk_customer_order_customer` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

When flushing the EntityManager here:

```
private void addOrderedItems(CustomerOrder order, ShoppingCart cart) {

    em.flush(); //Here

    List<ShoppingCartItem> items = cart.getItems();

    for (ShoppingCartItem scItem : items) {

        int productId = scItem.getProduct().getId();

        OrderedProductPK orderedProductPK = new OrderedProductPK();
        orderedProductPK.setCustomerOrderId(order.getId());
        orderedProductPK.setProductId(productId);

        OrderedProduct orderedItem = new OrderedProduct(orderedProductPK);

        orderedItem.setQuantity(scItem.getQuantity());

        em.persist(orderedItem);
    }
}
```

My full OrderManager code is visible here:

`http://pastebin.com/jRintrTS`

Please correct me otherwise, but from what I can understand about the error, I am trying to insert a row in the `customer_order` table but cannot do this as the foreign key reference to `customer_id` does not exist in the `customer` table. However, I have created the customer and persisted it before the order, so I don't understand why it isn't committing the data to the database before attempting to create a CustomerOrder.

This is the schema sql provided by netbeans for the e-commerce project:

https://netbeans.org/projects/samples/sources/samples-source-code/content/samples/javaee/AffableBean/setup/schemaCreation.sql

And my persistence.xml file, identical to the one provided in the tutorial:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="LarrysPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/larrys</jta-data-source>
        <properties/>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The only thing different about my project and the NetBeans project is that in my `customer` table, I have changed `cityRegion` to `town`, added `postcode` and `county`, and my project uses a different name to AffableBean.

Has anyone got any ideas as to where I might be going wrong?

EDIT - GlassFish Log when encountering the error:

```
[2015-06-11T21:18:57.799+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [FINE] [] [org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/OBFUSCATED/Larrys/out/artifacts/Larrys/WEB-INF/classes/_LarrysPU.sql] [tid: _ThreadID=26 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(2)] [timeMillis: 1434053937799] [levelValue: 500] [[
  INSERT INTO larrys.customer (id, address, cc_number, county, email, name, phone, postcode, town) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [9 parameters bound]]]

[2015-06-11T21:18:57.800+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [FINEST] [] [org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/OBFUSCATED/Larrys/out/artifacts/Larrys/WEB-INF/classes/_LarrysPU.query] [tid: _ThreadID=26 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(2)] [timeMillis: 1434053937800] [levelValue: 300] [[
  Execute query InsertObjectQuery(entity.CustomerOrder@1f3cec0)]]

[2015-06-11T21:18:57.801+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [FINE] [] [org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/OBFUSCATED/Larrys/out/artifacts/Larrys/WEB-INF/classes/_LarrysPU.sql] [tid: _ThreadID=26 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(2)] [timeMillis: 1434053937801] [levelValue: 500] [[
  INSERT INTO larrys.customer_order (id, amount, confirmation_number, date_created, customer_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [5 parameters bound]]]

[2015-06-11T21:18:57.802+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [FINE] [] [org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/OBFUSCATED/Larrys/out/artifacts/Larrys/WEB-INF/classes/_LarrysPU.sql] [tid: _ThreadID=26 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(2)] [timeMillis: 1434053937802] [levelValue: 500] [[
  SELECT 1]]

[2015-06-11T21:18:57.802+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/OBFUSCATED/Larrys/out/artifacts/Larrys/WEB-INF/classes/_LarrysPU] [tid: _ThreadID=26 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(2)] [timeMillis: 1434053937802] [levelValue: 900] [[

Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`larrys`.`customer_order`, CONSTRAINT `fk_customer_order_customer` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
Error Code: 1452
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the issue I encountered was caused by the fact my Id accessors had no `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`, so I added this for each Entity.

As for fixing the `Unknown column 'SOMETHING' in 'field list'` error I received, it turns out I only received this for the OrderedProduct class. Instead of using the @Annotations on fields, I chose to use them on their accessor methods, which could allow for customization in the future; but I forgot about this:

```
@EmbeddedId
protected OrderedProductPK orderedProductPK;
```

where the `@EmbeddedId` annotation should have been present on an accessor for the OrderedProductPK.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing there is a customerId property on OrderedProduct and you need to call orderedItem.setCustomerId() or orderedItem.setCustomer() with a valid customer id or valid customer object depending on how you've created the entity classes.  These seem to be the only two lines that set values on the orderedItem object.

```
// order id
orderedProductPK.setCustomerOrderId(order.getId());
// product id
orderedProductPK.setProductId(productId);
// object created with order and product associations
OrderedProduct orderedItem = new OrderedProduct(orderedProductPK);
// quantity set
orderedItem.setQuantity(scItem.getQuantity());
// customer is not associated
```

A customer needs to be associated with the orderedItem.

EDIT:
Looking at the tutorial it looks like customer is associated with the order object.  What do you get for order.getCustomer()? If it is null, that's your problem.

Comment: Before I call the `addOrderedItems` method, I am also calling `addCustomer` and `addOrder`. The full code for OrderManager is visible here - http://pastebin.com/jRintrTS - the error occurs at `em.flush();`, before it reaches the orderedItem line.

Comment: `order.getCustomer()` doesn't return null, it returns the Customer object assigned to the order.

Comment: I guess that's not it, sorry.  Can you do order.getCustomer().getId()?  Is the customer persisted as part of the same transaction? If yes, what happens if you try to persist the customer first? If no, can you query the database directly to make sure the customer record is there? This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769865/how-to-populate-foreign-key-values-in-a-hibernate-spring-jpa-configuration-whe

Comment: I literally just solved this - turns out, I forgot to add `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` annotations to my ids in my Entities. However, I've run into a new issue. When the SQL query is executed, I am given a bunch of errors: `Unknown column 'PRODUCTID' in 'field list'` - Apparently it's something to do with naming strategies, and it seems to be ignoring my `@Column` annotations. Any clues?